# Can someone change the information a website receives from a MySql database

Tags: php, mysql

lets say I had the following code:

```
   $fetchlast1 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tableOne WHERE name='billy'");
   while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($fetchlast1)) {
                    $id = $row[1];
                    if($id == '23'){
                     //give admin privileges.
                    } 
   }
```

So lets say the value of $id turns out to be '45' NOT '23'. Can a skilled person or anyone at all somehow change the recieved value to be '23' and hence get admin privileges?

Comment: If there isn't any user input, then I'd say no. You really should switch to the newer APIs though.

Comment: For static queries there is no way as correctly pointed by @Fred-ii-

Comment: ***Please [stop using `mysql_*` functions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php).*** [These extensions](http://php.net/manual/en/migration70.removed-exts-sapis.php) have been removed in PHP 7. Learn about [prepared](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) statements for [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) and [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and consider using PDO, [it's really pretty easy](http://jayblanchard.net/demystifying_php_pdo.html).

Comment: The results of your queries can only be changed if you are NOT using parameterized queries.

Comment: When someone doesn't have the admin privileges, do you create the admin controls and hide them with CSS or are they excluded from the page all together? If they are just hidden, someone could use the browsers inspector tool to make those controls visible

Answer (score -1):

The answer is **yes** and **no**. If your values are hardcored in the code then there is no chance of SQL Injection. It depends on the way you are including `'billy'` in your query (read more [mysqli prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php)). Also your logistic operation does not have any sence when used with this query.

I also **STRONGLY** recommend you start programming in PHP using **mysqli** (MySQL improved syntax).

Comment: [Yeah, I said that.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40494811/can-someone-change-the-information-a-website-receives-from-a-mysql-database#comment68233738_40494811)

Comment: the added prepared statements was a bonus ;-)

Comment: Wow, lot's of comments as answers today.